# Quais códigos usar para adicionar zoom na câmera?

Tags: android, android-camera

Meu grupo está fazendo um aplicativo com câmera. Só que não sabemos que código usar para adicionar zoom na câmera. Alguém sabe como fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Isso abaixo irá funcionar se o Android do usuário for:

- API 8 +

---

```
   Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
   int maxZoom = parameters.getMaxZoom(); 
      if (parameters.isZoomSupported()) {
        if (zoom >=0 && zoom < maxZoom) {
         parameters.setZoom(zoom);
      } else {
        // zoom parameter incorreto
      }
     }
```